# Django: order_by and filter on integer fields

Tags: python, django

I have this:

#models.py

```
from django.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    result = models.IntegerField()
```

#views.py

```
 def MyView(request):
    foo = MyModel.objects.order_by('result')
    return render_to_response('foo.html', {'foo': foo})
```

And instead of integer values sorted this way:

1, 3, 5, 24, 45

I get:

1, 24, 3, 45, 5 (sorted as strings)

And the solution is:

#views.py

```
def MyView(request):
    foo = MyModel.objects.all()
    foo = foo.extra(select={'result': 'CAST(result AS INTEGER)'}).extra(order_by = ['result'])
    return render_to_response('foo.html', {'foo': foo})
```

I want something like this (filter as integers, not as strings):

#views.py

```
def MyView(request):
    foo = MyModel.objects.all()
    foo = MyModel.objects.filter(result__gt = 50)
```

And it returns e.g.: 6, 7, 9; it doesn't return e.g. 100, 200 etc.

How this should be done?

Comment: Are you sure the `result` db column is actually an `IntegerField`? Your results seem to point to a `CharField`.  If you change the field type after syncdb, it will not go in and update the database to the new type.

Comment: You are right. I thought syncdb would update each of my change. And it wasn't true. What I've done was deleting the database and make it from scratch. And now it's working.

Comment: Using South (http://south.aeracode.org/) will help alleviate frustrating problems like that in the future. I too found it odd that the built-in syncdb didn't fire alter-table statements. Before south, it was a real pain in the butt to keep models and the db in sync.

Answer (score 0):

I have had this issue before it occurs when the database field is set to Char / Varchar instead of Int.

You will need to go into the database and alter the field type to ensure you can sort and filter correctly.